# UITextView starts in the middle of the text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

How to edit `UITextView` to show the text from the first word and not from the middle of the text in storyboards?

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot?

Comment: Please share more details.

Comment: You can do this in 2 ways. If your textView is in storyboard then go to property of textview > Alignment chose first one. If your adding programmatically then 

yourTextView.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

In Xcode->Open storyboard->Go to attributes inspector->TextView->Alignment->Choose left alignment.

If you want to make it by Code:

```
//textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
```

or

```
//[textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;
```

Comment: The poster has asked for advice with storyboards not in code

Comment: Great,  thats it, answers the question now.  You can always put your previous answer like that  as a comment when you have more rep in the future as it was still useful

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot or share some more details about how you are doing?

Comment: I can. But correction, it works on all devices exept iPhone 4s

Comment: Try this self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false;

Answer (score 0):

Xcode->Open storyboard->Go to attributes inspector->TextView->Alignment->Use fourth option in alignment

Answer (score 0):

You can set the alignment in the storyboard itself as you can see in attached screenshot.

[image]